# Where should I expect the Cache to be refilled? C

Tags: c, matrix, cpu-cache

I just recently found out about cache misses, specifically when I was designing matrix multiplications.

Having this tiled code that multiplies a matrix and a vector:

```
void aiMatMulVec_raw(const mFloat *M, const mFloat *V, const size_t nSize, mFloat *W) {
    
    for (size_t i = 0, k = min(i + nTile, nSize); i < nSize; i = k) {
        memset(W + i, 0, (k - i) * sizeof(mFloat));
        for (size_t j = 0, l = min(j + nTile, nSize); j < nSize; j = l)
            for (size_t x = i; x < k; x++) {
                mFloat value = 0.0f;
                mFloat *mPtr = M + x * nSize;
                for (size_t y = j; y < l; y++)
                    value += mPtr[y] * V[y];
                W[x] += value;
            };
    };
    
};
```

The efficiency went up by a lot using this 4 loops, instead of 2, with large matrices; but I wanted to find the most efficient tile size. And when I looked up the Cache Line size of the process' mask, trying to come up with a function that determines a good tile size, these questions appeared:

1. Where should I expect a refill of the cache?
2. Should I consider `__builtin_prefetch` to best determine such thing?
3. Does a cache block include multiple pointers (buffers) or only one?

Comment: It is very difficult to predict the performance based on the cache architecture.  Just try it and see,

Comment: Cache is refilled automatically by the processor when it attempts to load something that is not in cache (but is in memory marked as cacheable) or when such a load triggers additional preloading of other cache lines in anticipation they will be used. So it occurs incrementally as your program works through data.

Comment: Sure, you consider `__builtin_prefetch`.

Comment: Cache blocks do not have “pointers”. Cache caches data from memory, whatever type of data it is. Cache geometry varies between processor models. There are a variety of ways for hardware designers to configure cache.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a good way to convey a good understanding of cache geometries and behaviors. Generally, this information should be sought in textbooks and other primers and followed up with processor manuals, experience, and measurement.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for your detailed answer, I'll read into it more.